# How to configure Windows to survive power outages?

Tags: windows, shutdown, power

I have several PCs working in environment where the power is often unpredictably switched off.

There is some kind of capacitor backup that keeps the power for 1 second after the power outage.

Using bigger UPS is impossible, because of some technical conditions. The computers **must** shut down very short after the power is switched off.

The computers must run Windows because of the software.

Because of the above reasons, the Windows very often is damaged after the power outages and need to be restored from the backup images.

**What can we make to configure Windows more resistant to power outage?**

Loss of unsaved data is totally acceptable, but not the OS damaged.

**As a alternative variant if Windows can safely shut down for this 1 second provided by the capacitor backup, how to configure it to do so?**

Comment: You should be able to get a UPS that talks to Windows and tells Windows to hibernate or shut down. Alternatively, use something like https://horizondatasys.com/reboot-restore-rx/ to refresh Windows from an image every boot - now it doesn't matter if your current install is fried because you nuke it regularly anyway.

Comment: @SirAdelaide Using UPS is impossible. Every power **must** be switched off for 1 seconds or similar.

Comment: What version of Windows? Which filesystem?

Comment: @grawity - Windows 10. The file system is NTFS, afaik.

Comment: You will be unable to shutdown Windows within 1 second. If you cannot predict when the power will go out then you will need to invest in a UPS and configure the system to shutdown immediately when the power goes out.

Comment: @Ramhound It is not about investments. The technical conditions require to switch off **all** power sources in 1..2 seconds. Unfortunately, using UPS of any kind is impossible.

Comment: Your technical requirements are impossible to achieve if your not willing to deal with data corruption and other side effects

Comment: @Ramhound As I wrote in the question - some data corruption is OK. Only the OS corruption is not acceptable. I have Linux machines working in similar conditions and there everything is fine after the power outage.

Answer (score 3):

If changing OS is an option you could switch your PCs to Windows 10 iot. This variant of Windows is designed for use on industrial equipment that suffers frequent power outages. It uses a write filter to protect the system partition from corruption by caching any changes in a ram disk. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/secure-your-device/unifiedwritefilter

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the chance of a damage, you can disable disk cache completely. This will force windows to write changes immediately, which will not prevent your problems, but it will minimize the data loss.

This might impact the speed especially with many small writes, but you can give it a try.

[Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324805/how-to-manually-turn-disk-write-caching-on-or-off)

---

You might also want to disable [NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959914.aspx). This will prevent the system to make changes to the file system even if it only reads a file.

---

Also you should disable all automatic updates, because a power failure while running windows updates will cause problems.

Comment: According to the link, NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate is only for the directory listings, not for the file reading. Is it the right key, or there is another, that is for the file read operations?

Comment: Still it will reduce write accesses which will minimize the risk.

Comment: Yes, of course, but AFAIK the files also have metadata about the last access time. Is it possible to disable it as well?

Comment: Turing write caching off in Windows wont help much, as the disk controller and/or drives also have their own cache.  Not te mention whatever data is in RAM and the CPU caches.

Answer (score -1):

You could make every pc to make Image of the system, as often as you can.
Windows nor any software could 'protect' the system in 1 second time, not so far 2018, not so far I heard.
I'm wondering the type of environment where these computers are that you can't add UPS to each computer, if it is about space, there are some Power Supply w/UPS builtin at the market, you can replace with it, and have the ups builtin in your pcs (I think you are talking about desktop pc).
You need around a minutes to get windows shut down properly if it is not too loaded. I do recommend SSD disk to speed up any process, my pc shut down windows in few seconds w/SSD.
But, seriously and with all due respect, instead to look for a rabbit out of an impossible hat, I'd suggest you strongly to find out a way to fix with UPS/software in any way around, even if you can't fix the frequent power outage.

Comment: This is an industrial environment that can in some circumstances be polluted with highly explodable gas in dangerous concentrations. That is why there is a special system that measures the gas concentrations and if they are above some very low limit, switches all power down in order to prevent possible short circuits and explosions. That is why the UPS is not allowed and why the period of reaction is so short.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert, but since you want to protect the OS rather than the data, you may consider these workarounds:

- PCI reborn card (PCI recovery card). It wipes any changes to the OS after you reboot. In another word, it very quickly restore your system every time after power outage.
- Boot from network (PXE boot), to boot your machine from a system mirror file from another machine in LAN. This may bring another question that "how to protect the other PC from power outage", then using a laptop, or boot from a cloud server (like AWS) may work.
- Put your poor computer chasis out of the dangerous room, give it an UPS, and connect it through multiple very long cables for monitor (HDMI), mouse and keyboard (USB) from the dangerous room. There are products called "kvm extender over ethernet" that can extend all these cables in one.